# React TypeScript: How to make a ref?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, ref, react-ref

I'm building a React app using TypeScript. I'm using React-Slick's carousel.

I'm trying to programmatically change the slide of the carousel. Therefore I followed [the documentation](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slick-go-to/) and tried to create a ref for the Slider.

```
<Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
```

Now TypeScript complains that it does not now slider. So I tried declaring it like this:

```
slider: Slider | null;
```

If I try it like this, I get the error:

```
[ts] Property 'slider' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

How is one supposed to make a ref work with TypeScript?

The only way I could find was to say:

```
slide: any;
```

which defeats the purpose of TypeScript .

**EDIT:**
[Tolle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) you marked this question as a duplicate. But it is different, in that here the ref is created this way:

```
ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}
```

And in your proposed original question this way:

```
ref={this.stepInput}
```