# React TypeScript: How to make a ref using c => (this.c = c)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, ref, react-ref

**NOTE:** I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197283/react-typescript-how-to-make-a-ref) previously. [Tolle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) you marked that question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796267/how-to-use-refs-in-react-with-typescript) question. But it is different, in that in my case the ref is created this way:

```
ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}
```

And in your proposed original question this way:

```
ref={this.stepInput}
```

The answer for your proposed original was to do it this way:

```
private sliderRef = createRef<Slider>();
// ...
<Slider {...settings} slide={classes.slide} ref={this.sliderRef}>
```

But then I can't do:

```
next = () => {
  this.sliderRef.slickNext();
};
```

because I get the error:

```
[ts] Property 'slickNext' does not exist on type 'RefObject<Slider>'.
```

**With this being said, here is the question**:

I'm building a React app using TypeScript. I'm using React-Slick's carousel.

I'm trying to programmatically change the slide of the carousel. Therefore I followed [the documentation](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods) and tried to create a ref for the Slider.

```
<Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
```

Now TypeScript complains that it does not know slider. So I tried declaring it like this:

```
slider: Slider | null;
```

If I try it like this, I get the error:

```
[ts] Property 'slider' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

How is one supposed to make a ref work with TypeScript?

The only way I could find was to say:

```
slide: any;
```

which defeats the purpose of TypeScript .

Comment: The reason I closed your other question as duplicate is because the accepted answer is a two-part answer where one of the solutions is the callback ref method you are using. Please read it more closely.

Comment: @Tholle Oh wow, you were right. I'm so dumb, I'm sorry!